# How can we use smb protocol in Qt?

Tags: qt4, symbian, protocols, smb

I m working on a project "Wireless File Sharing Between Computer and Mobile Phone"
nokia phone using symbian and Qt. required no server is running on the system.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qt is not a do-it-all solution (if it would, it would be bloated like the Java runtime), so does not implement SMB. You will have to use something like libsmbclient instead.

Comment: How i can use libsmbclient in my project?